# returning customer vs new customer

Tags: user-behavior, conversion

Currently I am using the below scenario for returning customers and new customers. The address form is beneath. So if you are a new customer we require email and phone, but if you are returning then you can login.

[image]

I was wondering if there are any proven methods to help the visitor more clearly. What I was contemplating was something closer to having two buttons, NEW CUSTOMER, RETURNING CUSTOMER, and then showing the correct fields onclick. Anyone have any suggestions of experience in such matters?

Comment: Is there a CTA somewhere for the new customer? Also, the text seems to be written by a programmer as it says "Else if you are a new customer". You should try to use text as if you were speaking to a human in real life.

Comment: true, well I am a programmer, I guess its just in my nature.

Comment: What about two boxes side by side, I resent the having an extra page for the visitors to navigate through, I think its much better delivering it to the same page. So if the fields were in two boxes side by side clearly outlining new and used, would that be better?

Comment: What is the *user scenario*? Is the user landing on the page, or is she checking out?

Comment: Checking out, below are the address and payment forms.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

My approach would be to break them apart.

Putting too many fields would clutter the screen and give redundant fields. My approach would be breaking them up into 2 screens. In addition, according to many articles out there, returning customers have a higher ratio compared to new customers.

Hence, I suggest putting the existing customer as the primary login page and accessing a new customer page through another link as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Let the user do everything on website without login.
When he wants to check out propose a box like that.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT5jUl.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

For returning custumers everything is fine. For new user you move them to another page where he could create a full account or simply give you his phone number. 
 When a customer give you email, phone, delivery address with only one more field password you could finish the account creation or let the user order without account it's up to him.

Comment: haha! you read my mind! :))

Answer (score 0):

Since the e-mail address is a common field for both type of users i could suggest a similar solution that i have seen in e-commerce websites.

1) user has to enter his e-mail address
2) if that e-mail address is already in the websites database a password field appears, if not the telephone field. Or just put two radio buttons under the e-mail address as shown in my mock up bellow.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1fTzu.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I am trying to avoid this extra step

Comment: can you make the system automatically to detect through e-mail address if the user is new or returning?

That would avoid those radio buttons

Comment: by saving IP address? But they would still need to enter their username and password. 
I'm not down with the radio buttons anyway, I think there are definitely better alternatives than that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends partly on the scenario. Is the user just landing on the page, or is she checking out?

In the case of **landing** on a page where normal usage requires a **constant log on**, you have an area showing who is logged in (typically upper right). That is where your eyes will go, looking for who is logged in or not, and is a suitable spot for the login button. The signup can be placed neatly adjacent to it, separately, but in the spacious page body where it can't be missed.

[image]

In the case of checking out, it depends on your process, but I recommend not to scare off the user with lots of fields in the cruisal bring-out-your-wallet moment. Amazon separates it, so that the initial step is effortless, in their **checkout process**. Your first investment is simple: Type your email:

[image]

And in any form, use the browser's autofill capability.

Comment: But having this extra sign in process is one extra step, that I am trying to avoid.